# Can a conditional sentence contain more than one "if"?

Tags: grammar, conditionals

For example, is the following sentence correct?

- *If you have 100 books, how many can you give away if you want to keep at least 20 of them?*

I'd appreciate it if you could provide links where I can read about this rule.

Thank you so much :)

Comment: I doubt anyone would have defined a "rule" simply to confirm that there's nothing inherently incorrect about "repeating / stacking / nesting" conditional elements in a single utterance in English (whether marked by the specific word ***if*** or using other means - for example, replacing the second instance of ***if*** in the cited example by, say, ***assuming***). It just ***is*** okay - we don't need a rule telling us that!

Comment: Another sentence with  two "if"s.  "If you have 100 books, and if you want to keep only 20 of them, how many can you give away?"

Comment: There are arguably two levels of condition here. The first one is global, scene-setting. It doesn't need an 'if' in the typical traditional style of a simple maths question. _A man has 100 books._  A rather more stylish rendering would be _How many books could a man give away if he has 100 and wants to keep at least 20 of them?_ Here, the two conditions (factors, constraints, inputs) proposed are given equal 'ranking'. // Using two _if_'s is not so serious a style offence. //// Note that the correct answer here is '80 or less/fewer'.

Comment: If you have 100 books and want to keep at least 20, how many can you give away.

Comment: @RegDwigнt: Logically that's equivalent to (and interchangeable with *If you have 100 books and **if you** want to keep at least 20...*. And Edwin - I see no reason to promote one of those conditions above the other. It wouldn't make any difference if it was expressed as *If you want to keep at least 20 books and **if you** have 100...*

Comment: "If we had some ham we could have ham and eggs, if we had some eggs"

Comment: @FumbleFingers precisely my point. It is logically equivalent, so they can safely use it instead of the mouthful they're struggling with now.

Answer (score -2):

The sentence does not sound grammatically incorrect. However, it'd be better to avoid using two ifs in a sentence as it seems to affect the flow. Breaking it into two short sentences should be better.